# Creating a method to modify elements in an array in Ruby with 2 arguments, one of them being the original array

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

I would like to create a method, `mod_method(array, n)` , where `array` is an array and `n` is a number. `mod_method` should take number `n` and add it to all internal numbers in `array` and return that new array.

For example, using `array = ["I", "have", 3, "to", 4, "hours"]`, how would I find `mod_method(array, 1)` such that

```
mod_method(array,1)
 => ["I", "have", 4, "to", 5, "hours"]
```

I'm a noob and was only able to do this using the already defined array and number (let's use 1), as such:

```
array = ["I", "have", 3, "to", 4, "hours"]
=>[[0] "I",
  [1] "have",
  [2] 3,
  [3] "to",
  [4] 4,
  [5] "hours"]

numbers = array.values_at(2, 4)
=> [
  [0] 3,
  [1] 4

mod = numbers.map{|x| x + 1}
=> [
  [0] 4,
  [1] 5]
new_array = ["I", "have", mod[0], "to", mod[1], "hours"]
=> ["I", "have", 4, "to", 5, "hours"]
```

I have no idea how to do it with undefined arguments for the `mod_method`.

Comment: Why is it you don't know which elements aren't numbers? And, why are there numbers mixed with strings? There's some code-smell implied by the array's contents.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what I would do.

```
def mod_method(array,n)
  array.map do |e|
    e.is_a?(Integer) ? e + n : e
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Write the method as

```
def mod_method(array, n)
  array.map { |i| i.is_a?(Fixnum) ? (i + n) : i }
end

array = ["I", "have", 3, "to", 4, "hours"]
mod_method(array, 1) # => ["I", "have", 4, "to", 5, "hours"]
```

If your array contains both `Fixnum` and `Float` instances, and you want to add `1` with either of those instances. Then use the below method :-

```
def mod_method(array, n)
  array.map { |i| i.kind_of?(Numeric) ? (i + n) : i }
end

array = ["I", "have", 3.2, "to", 4, "hours"]
mod_method(array, 1) # => ["I", "have", 4.2, "to", 5, "hours"]
```

Comment: Numeric would also cover Bignum, Rational, Complex, etc, so I'd definitely recommend `is_a?(Numeric)`, not `is_a?(Fixnum)`. You probably don't care about Rational and such, and may not care about Float, but you almost always want to cover Bignum in addition to Fixnum.